# 2006 Cobalt SS - Traction Control Light & Hard Shifting

Tags: automatic-transmission, chevrolet, shifting, cobalt, delta

I drive a 2006 Cobalt SS (not supercharged) with the 2.4L engine.

In the last month or so the traction control light has been coming on periodically. Turning the engine off and back on causes the light to go off. While the light is on I notice that when the car shifts gears (it's automatic, as you might have guessed) it does it quite a bit harder than normal.

Any ideas as to what may be the problem?

Comment: Any check engine light? Have you tried turning off the traction control? The instructions to do this are in the owners manual.

Answer (score 1):

TCS systems are pretty simple, generally. They basically use all the same hardware as the ABS system, so one probable fault would be a bad wheel speed sensor.

I'm struggling to think of anything to tie the TCS fault together with the hard shifting...

Comment: Vehicle speed sensor?